# Is there a way to highlight function calls using Pygments (or another library)?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, tokenize, lexer, pygments

I was quite disappointed to discover that functions calls were not highlighted using [Pygments](http://pygments.org/).

[image: Pygments Syntax Highlighting]

[See it online](http://pygments.org/demo/6641602/) (I tested it with all available styles)

Builtin functions are highlighted but not mine.

I looked at [the tokens list](http://pygments.org/docs/tokens/) but there is no reference to "function call" or "object attribute" for example.

I have considered extending the lexer by adding a regex rule like `\w+\(.*?\)`. But I am afraid to multiply the errors because of edge cases I did not think of.

Do you know why this feature is not implemented directly inside Pygments?

Comment: I'm also very interested in this!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific list of functions you want highlighted, you can add a custom highlighter like the builtin [`NumPyLexer`](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/a768fb9fea8a7a1137b4197a43381f85cad94c2e/pygments/lexers/python.py#L1079-L1172):

```py
from pygments.lexers.python import PythonLexer
from pygments.token import Keyword, Name, String

class MyFuncLexer(PythonLexer):
    name = 'MyFuncPython'
    aliases = ['myfuncpython']

    # override the mimetypes to not inherit them from python
    mimetypes = []
    filenames = []

    EXTRA_KEYWORDS = {
        'func'
    }

    def get_tokens_unprocessed(self, text):
        for index, token, value in \
                PythonLexer.get_tokens_unprocessed(self, text):
            if token is Name and value in self.EXTRA_KEYWORDS:
                yield index, Keyword.Pseudo, value
            else:
                yield index, token, value
```